# How to use less arguments for methods

Tags: c#, methods, arguments

I search my data inside table based on these arguments in this method.

```
public List<Product_tbl> GET_Product(int? ProductID = null, string Name= null, bool? MakeFlag= null, string Color= null)
{
   ...
}
```

I know I should have less argument for methods as much as I can, so is there any way that I can write my code clean and use less arguments for this kinds of methods.

Comment: You shouldn't try to alter perfectly working code to adhere to some abstract "too many parameters" principle.  Your method should have as many parameters as it makes sense to have.  Generalizations are there only to make you ask the question and think about whether your parameters are appropriate.

Comment: have you looked at default, or params for your method

Comment: Its kind of dynamic select query ,first I load my data into a list then I search based on argument

Comment: This kind of method-as-a-query is okay when your parameters represents a unique key. Otherwise, just don't do this. You'll end up having method calls that won't make sense or will interrogate too many data for nothing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because working code looking to be improved should be asked about on CodeReview.SE per its guidelines, not on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the arguments in a class instead.

```
public class ProductArgs
{
    public int? ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public bool? MakeFlag { get; set; }
}

public List GET_Product(ProductArgs p){ ... }
```

As the comments suggest, you shouldn't strive to reduce parameters for the sake of "clean" code. Having a class like this that is only used to represent arguments in a single method call shouldn't be done unless that class construct has other uses in your application. Don't be afraid to have 4 parameters in a method call, there's nothing necessarily "unclean" about that.

Comment: This information doesn't conceptually represent a logical type.  It makes no sense for them to be in a class together.  Nor does it do anything to address a fundamental problem of a method asking for more information than it should be.

Comment: ProductID should be nullable, based on the original question

Comment: it represents the arguments to the method, which is exactly what it  is trying to represent. the man asked for a way to cut down on the args, there you go. I agree that you shouldn't do this unless you plan on reusing this class, but i'm just answering his question.

Comment: @DLeh Your answering the question without *solving the problem*.  That's not actually being helpful.

Comment: @Servy There isn't nearly enough information to make that call. The original method suggests a better design could eliminate the need for this question, but we can only speculate.

Comment: @JamesRalston If there isn't enough information to answer the question then *ask for more information* rather than posting an unhelpful answer.  I agree entirely that there isn't enough information in this question to provide any meaningful answer.  This post is more or less like responding to the question of, "my floor has a bunch of dust, where should I put it all?" with,  "sweep it under the rug".  Yes, it does technically answer the question, but it's still not helpful.

Comment: @Servy there is enough to answer the question. This exactly answers  the question he asks. You're trying to infer some other question that he's not asking.

Comment: @DLeh As I said, there isn't enough information to provide an answer that would be *actually helpful*.  I stand by that.  This answer is not helpful at all, as it is doing nothing to solve the problem.

Comment: @Servy I agree in general, but the "more information" in this case would transcend the scope of the original question by quite a bit. I will concede, it should suggested in the answer to take a closer look at why this method exists and other factors.

Comment: @Servy I actually think this solves the "problem" stated by the user, however it is to discuss whether it actually *is* a problem. I have to admit though that `MakeFlag` should probably not in the `ProductArgs`, but that's just my interpratation. I think it should be omitted from the `ProductArgs` and put back in the method's args.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you just need to have a lot of arguments for methods. What you are doing with optional arguments is great, and I assume you already know you can do

```
GET_Product(Name:"blah");
```

The code you have seems fine, in my opinion, because all that will be required for most queries. Something to consider if you *really* had too many arguments is making a query class of some kind that could hold your arguments for you. This is more used in things like Java where optional arguments don't work. However, it should work if you need it to. For example:

```
MyQuery q = new MyQuery();
q.Name("Steve");
q.Id(42);
q.Color("pink");
GET_Product(q);
```

Comment: it's fine to have multiple answers on a question. Especially because the asker hasn't accepted an answer yet. You can leave out your `EDIT` at the top.